# Simultaneous AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search suggestion script that pulls results from two Google APIs, orders the results by an integer value and then displays it to a user.

However, currently the script doesn't appear to return results from the second API until the user has pressed enter or return. Why could this be?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8Kfx/

My code is:

```
var combined = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        $("#suggest").html("");
        $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q="+$("#search").val()+"&client=chrome&callback=?",function(data){
            for(var key in data[1]){
                if(data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key]=="NAVIGATION"){
                    combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'><a href='"+data[1][key]+"'>"+data[2][key]+"</a></li>");
                }else{
                    combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'>"+data[1][key]+"</li>");
                }
            }
        });
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="+$("#search").val()+"&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?",function(data){
            for(var key in data.result){
                combined.push("<li rel='"+Math.round(data.result[key].score*5)+"'> Freebase: "+data.result[key].name+"</li>");
            }
        });
        combined.sort(function(a,b){
             return +$(b).attr("rel") - +$(a).attr("rel");
        });
        $("#suggest").html(combined.slice(0, 5).join(""));
        combined = [];
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me in the fiddle. Check if the request is complete in firebug. Maybe the ajax is completing slowly in your case.

Comment: This is just a **side note** . Since this ajax is being triggered on keyup, you are potentially running many ajax requests at once. You should try assigning your ajax requests to a variable, and aborting pre-existing requests before processing new ones. http://jsfiddle.net/m8Kfx/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it **does** return values, but you have a timing issue here. You fill your list with results, before the requests have actually been finished. Try something like this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/jDvVL/1/

Also, since you're appending the result of your second request to your array, they will never show up due to your `.slice(0,5)`, so I removed that.

Comment: Well, basically `.slice(0.5)` is right, I just removed it so that you can see that it actually returns results from both API requests.

Comment: Well the problem is that the second API returns other `relevance` values than the first one, so it's hard to decide which of them is more relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var allData = []
$.getJSON("/values/1", function(data) {
    allData.push(data);
    if(data.length == 2){
      processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
    }
});

$.getJSON("/values/2", function(data) {
    allData.push(data);
    if(data.length == 2){
        processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
    }
});

var processData = function(data){
     var sum = data[0] + data[1]
     $('#mynode').html(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the secong getJSON in the first, like this.  Nice code BTW.

```
var combined = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("#suggest").html("");
    $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q="+$("#search").val()+"&client=chrome&callback=?",function(data){
        for(var key in data[1]){
            if(data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key]=="NAVIGATION"){
                combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'><a href='"+data[1][key]+"'>"+data[2][key]+"</a></li>");
            }else{
                combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'>"+data[1][key]+"</li>");
            }
        }

                $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="+$("#search").val()+"&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?",function(data){
        for(var key in data.result){
            combined.push("<li rel='"+Math.round(data.result[key].score*5)+"'> Freebase: "+data.result[key].name+"</li>");
        }
    });

    });



    combined.sort(function(a,b){
         return +$(b).attr("rel") - +$(a).attr("rel");
    });
    $("#suggest").html(combined.slice(0, 5).join(""));
    combined = [];
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things about the code.

The sorting and appending should be called in the callbacks of the ajax functions, this can be achieved by making another function that handles sorting and display.  Then call this function in the success callback.

Second, the freemarker results are showing up, however they are always sent to the bottom of the list.  If you view 200 of your results they are at the bottom.

```
var combined = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        $("#suggest").html("");
        $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q="+$("#search").val()+"&client=chrome&callback=?",function(data){
            for(var key in data[1]){
                if(data[4]["google:suggesttype"][key]=="NAVIGATION"){
                    combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'><a href='"+data[1][key]+"'>"+data[2][key]+"</a></li>");
                }else{
                    combined.push("<li rel='"+data[4]["google:suggestrelevance"][key]+"'>"+data[1][key]+"</li>");
                }
            }
            sortAndDisplay(combined);
        });
        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="+$("#search").val()+"&limit=3&encode=html&callback=?",function(data){
            for(var key in data.result){
                combined.push("<li rel='"+Math.round(data.result[key].score*5)+"'> Freebase: "+data.result[key].name+"</li>");
            }
            sortAndDisplay(combined);
        });
    });
});

function sortAndDisplay(combined){
        combined.sort(function(a,b){
             return +$(b).attr("rel") - +$(a).attr("rel");
        });
        $("#suggest").html(combined.slice(0, 200).join(""));
        combined = [];
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/m8Kfx/4/